# Adding to an array with select case

Tags: vba, excel

Hope someone can help with a puzzling problem.

I have an excel worksheet that has a lot of lines that need to be moved to different sheets.

I have a select case statement that sets 3 variables to true or false depending on whether the numbers in the first column match a case statement. This works ok but I now want to add a name to an array if the value is true.

The select case statement is as follows :

```
While LContinue
    If LRow = Lastrow Then
        LContinue = False
    Else
        Select Case Range("A" & LRow).Value
            Case 30 To 39
                MainSheet = True
                'Tabs(0) = "Main"
            Case 40 To 49
                SecondSheet = True
                'Tabs(1) = "Second"
            Case 111 To 112
                ThirdSheet = True
                'Tabs(2) = "Third"
        End Select
        LRow = LRow + 1
    End If
Wend
```

This is used to see if I need to add the sheet or not. to add the sheets I use the following code :

```
For i = LBound(Tabs) To UBound(Tabs)
    Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = Tabs(i)
Next i
```

So what I would like to know is how would I go about adding the sheetnames to the array but only if the value in the select case is true.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why not use worksheet function '**CountIfs**'?

*It counts on multiple criteria and you do not need any loops so your code will run quicker.*

> **CountIfs**(testedRange, **">=30"**, testedRange, **"<=39"**)

... calculates number of values in 'testedRange' which are >=30 and <=39. If there is at least one then just add your sheet, that's it. No loops, no arrays, no additional variables needed. HTH.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim testedRange As Range
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    Lastrow = 10
    Set testedRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow)

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        If .CountIfs(testedRange, ">=30", testedRange, "<=39") > 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Main"
        End If

        If .CountIfs(testedRange, ">=40", testedRange, "<=49") > 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Second"
        End If

        If .CountIfs(testedRange, ">=111", testedRange, "<=112") > 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Third"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel VBA is not very flexible when it come to working with actual arrays. But you can work with a collection instead:

```
SET tabs = new Collection
```

And then you can `add` a new value to it whenever you need to (e.g. in the CASE structure):

```
  .
  ..
  ...
  Case 40 To 49
    SecondSheet = True
    Tabs.add "Second"
  ...
  ..
```

The values of the collection can be accessed almost in the same way as those of an array:

```
for j=1 to tabs.count
   Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = tabs(j)
next j
```

**Edit:**

Since the code is re-entrant, i.e. there can be several instances when `Range("A" & LRow).Value` will be evaluated, we must make sure, that an item is set only once. This can be done easiest with a dictionary (instead of a collection):

```
Set tabs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Now it is easy to establish, whether a particular page has already been defined before:

```
..
...
Case 40 To 49
    SecondSheet = True    
    tabs("Second")=1
```

The page creation loop then looks like this

```
for each k in tabs.keys
   Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = k
next k
```

The loop iterates over the keys only. There is no need to check for duplicate entries as all unique keys will be defined and listed only once!

Comment: If the 'tabs' collection will be used this way then it won't work correctly I'm afraid. Collection could contain the same string many times. E.g. in cell 'a1' is '35' and in 'a2' '36' then 'Main' will be added twice...and the next for-loop will fail to add the sheets with same name.

Comment: So add item to tabs collection only once: If (MainSheet = False) Then tabs.Add "Main"
                    MainSheet = True

Answer (score 0):

To do this with an array you would want to:

- declare a dynamic array of strings
- declare a counter for the number of elements added
- set the array's size to the largest value that it could possibly be
- assign elements to the array, incrementing the counter for each addition
- resize the array using the counter value (or test for empty elements when accessing array)

In code that could translate into something like:

```
Dim Tabs() as String
Dim counter As Long
...
Redim Tabs(0 to Lastrow)
counter = 0
...
While ...
   Select Case .Range("A" & lrow).Value
       Case 30 To 39
           Mainsheet = True
           Tabs(count) = "Main"
       ...
       Case Else
           counter = counter - 1
   End Select
   counter = counter + 1
   ...
Wend
If Not counter = 0 Then
    Redim Preserve Tab(0 to counter - 1)
    ...
    'create worksheets using Tabs(), etc.
    ...
End If
```